# recodeSNPs function in r does not handle NAs in the input matrix

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I am using a function in R called recodeSNPs (from package scrime) as follows:

```
recodeSNPs(mat, first.ref = FALSE, geno = 1:3, snp.in.col = TRUE)
```

Where mat is "a matrix or data frame consisting of character strings of length 2 that specify the genotypes of the SNPs. Each of these character strings must be a combination of the letters A, T, C, and G. Missing values can be specified by "NN" or NA. Depending on snp.in.col it is assumed that each row of mat represents a SNP and each column a variable (snp.in.col = FALSE), or vice versa."

My csv file looks like this:

```
geno<-read.table("Euc_geno4.csv", sep=";", colClasses="character", header=T, na.strings="NA")

geno<-as.matrix(geno)

X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9   X10  X11  X12  X13  X14  X15 
  [1,] "GA" NA   "CC" "GA" "AA" "CC" "AA" "AA" "GG" "TT" "TT" "TT" "GG" "GG" "CC"
  [2,] "GG" NA   "CC" "AA" "AA" "CC" "GG" "AA" "GG" "CC" "TT" "TT" "GG" "GG" "CC"
  [3,] "GG" NA   "CT" "AA" "AA" "CC" "GG" "AA" "GC" "TT" "TT" "TT" "GG" "GG" "CC"
  [4,] "AA" "CT" "CC" "GA" "AA" "CC" "GG" "AA" "GC" "TT" "TT" "TT" "GA" "GG" "CC"
```

etc.
Where the SNPs are in columns.

However, when I try to use the function:

```
recodeSNPs(geno, geno=0:2)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error in checkATCG(mat, first.ref = first.ref) : 

  All values in mat must be combinations of length 2 of
the letters A, T, C and G.
```

I don't really understand, as my matrix includes only A, T, C and G (and NA). If I generate a random matrix:

```
mat <- matrix("", 10, 12)
mat[c(1, 4, 6),] <- sample(c("AA", "AT", "TT"), 18, TRUE)
mat[c(2, 3, 10),] <- sample(c("CC", "CG", "GG"), 18, TRUE)
mat[c(5, 8),] <- sample(c("GG", "GT", "TT"), 12, TRUE)
mat[c(7, 9),] <- sample(c("AA", "AC", "CC"), 12, TRUE)
mat
```

It looks like this:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,] "AA" "AA" "TT" "AT" "AT" "AT" "AA" "AA" "TT" "AT"  "AT"  "AT" 
 [2,] "CG" "CG" "CG" "GG" "CC" "CG" "CG" "CG" "CG" "GG"  "CC"  "CG" 
 [3,] "GG" "GG" "GG" "GG" "CG" "CC" "GG" "GG" "GG" "GG"  "CG"  "CC" 
 [4,] "AT" "AT" "TT" "AT" "AT" "TT" "AT" "AT" "TT" "AT"  "AT"  "TT" 
 [5,] "GT" "TT" "GG" "TT" "TT" "GG" "GT" "TT" "GG" "TT"  "TT"  "GG" 
 [6,] "AA" "AA" "AT" "TT" "AT" "TT" "AA" "AA" "AT" "TT"  "AT"  "TT" 
 [7,] "AC" "AC" "CC" "CC" "AC" "AC" "AC" "AC" "CC" "CC"  "AC"  "AC" 
 [8,] "TT" "GG" "GG" "TT" "TT" "GT" "TT" "GG" "GG" "TT"  "TT"  "GT" 
 [9,] "CC" "AA" "AC" "CC" "AA" "AC" "CC" "AA" "AC" "CC"  "AA"  "AC" 
[10,] "GG" "CG" "CC" "GG" "GG" "GG" "GG" "CG" "CC" "GG"  "GG"  "GG"
```

And when I try execute the function using the random matrix:

```
recodeSNPs(mat, geno=0:2)
```

The results are perfect:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    0    0    2    1    1    1    0    0    2     1     1     1
 [2,]    1    1    1    2    0    1    1    1    1     2     0     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0     0     1     2
 [4,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0     1     1     0
 [5,]    1    0    2    0    0    2    1    0    2     0     0     2
 [6,]    0    0    1    2    1    2    0    0    1     2     1     2
 [7,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0     1     1
 [8,]    0    2    2    0    0    1    0    2    2     0     0     1
 [9,]    2    0    1    2    0    1    2    0    1     2     0     1
[10,]    0    1    2    0    0    0    0    1    2     0     0     0
```

So the function is somehow not seeing my values as being in the correct format, but I really don't know what to do next. I tried adding `text=c("AA", "CC", "GG", "TT", "AG", "AT", "AC", "GA", "GT", "GA", "TA", "TC", "TG", "CT", "CG", "CA")` when I import the csv, but still I get the same results.

Please help!

Comment: Does the `geno` object you have shown contain the full dataset or is it just the first couple of lines? If it *isn't* the full dataset could you provide a link to it or dump enough lines to force the error?

Comment: We've subsequently figured that although the documentation states that NAs are allowed, the checkATCG function called by recodeSNPs rejects a matrix with anything other than A T G and C in it. When I make a random matrix with NAs in it, it is also rejected.